# Slow response for right click context menu in Eclipse Package Explorer view

Tags: eclipse, performance, ide

I am using `Spring Tool Suite` 3.7 (Eclipse Mars). I have noticed that the right-click context menu takes time (5-6 sec) to load in the `Package Explorer` view.

Is there any tweak to load it fast?

Comment: Well I am not sure if updating to a newer release of Eclipse solved this issue.

Comment: tried the new version today, still slow